# R - identify which columns contain currency data $

Tags: r, currency, data-cleaning

I have a very large dataset with some columns formatted as currency, some numeric, some character. When reading in the data all currency columns are identified as factor and I need to convert them to numeric. The dataset it too wide to manually identify the columns. I am trying to find a programmatic way to identify if a column contains currency data (ex. starts with '$') and then pass that list of columns to be cleaned.

```
name <- c('john','carl', 'hank')
salary <- c('$23,456.33','$45,677.43','$76,234.88')
emp_data <- data.frame(name,salary)

clean <- function(ttt){
as.numeric(gsub('[^a-zA-z0-9.]','', ttt))
}
sapply(emp_data, clean)
```

The issue in this example is that this sapply works on all columns resulting in the name column being replaced with NA. I need a way to programmatically identify just the columns that the clean function needs to be applied to.. in this example salary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `stringr` packages, you can use `mutate_if` to identify columns that have any string starting with a `$` and then change the accordingly.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

emp_data %>%
  mutate_if(~any(str_detect(., '^\\$'), na.rm = TRUE),
            ~as.numeric(str_replace_all(., '[$,]', '')))
```

Comment: Thank you zack, this is wonderfully concise and does exactly what I was trying to accomplish!

Comment: @zack what does the `~` do?

Comment: `~as.numeric(str_replace_all(., '[$,]', ''))` could be replaced with `readr::parse_number`

Comment: @Aurèle, yeah I don't see why not. @Ben G, it's what signals the beginning of `purrr`-style anonymous function. [Quick blurb here if you're interested](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls03_map-function-syntax.html#anonymous_function,_formula). the `.` refers to the column input.

Comment: found 1 error. if the dataframe has a numeric or integer column the code errors out. I'm not familar with using these packages, is there a way to add an escape for these columns.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the error when i added an `integer` and `numeric` column to `emp_data`. That said, you can change the first line of the `mutate_if` call to `~any(str_detect(., '^\\$')) & !is.numeric(.)` to avoid those columns.

Comment: That worked, Thanks again! Might have something out of date causing the issue - will check... for reference the error message I got was "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: object 'NA' not found"

Comment: ah, i suspect that was happening because of `NA` values in a data column and the call to `any`, I've updated the code with a `na.rm = TRUE` argument passed.

Answer (score 1):

Taking advantage of the powerful parsers the `readr` package offers out of the box:

```
my_parser <- function(col) {
  # Try first with parse_number that handles currencies automatically quite well
  res <- suppressWarnings(readr::parse_number(col))
  if (is.null(attr(res, "problems", exact = TRUE))) {
    res
  } else {
    # If parse_number fails, fall back on parse_guess
    readr::parse_guess(col)
    # Alternatively, we could simply return col without further parsing attempt
  }
}

library(dplyr)

emp_data %>% 
  mutate(foo = "USD13.4",
         bar = "£37") %>% 
  mutate_all(my_parser)

#   name   salary  foo bar
# 1 john 23456.33 13.4  37
# 2 carl 45677.43 13.4  37
# 3 hank 76234.88 13.4  37
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option is to use `startsWith` to detect the dollar columns, and `gsub` to remove `"$"` and `","` from the columns.

```
doll_cols <- sapply(emp_data, function(x) any(startsWith(as.character(x), '$')))
emp_data[doll_cols] <- lapply(emp_data[doll_cols], 
                              function(x) as.numeric(gsub('\\$|,', '', x)))
```