# Removing parenthesis & dollar sign using gsub() in R?

Tags: r, string, gsub, parentheses, dollar-sign

I've imported a csv file to r. Few of my columns contains currency data (ex. starts with '$'). To remove the '$' and convert the into numeric type, I've used gsub() function and it works fine. 
Sample code is:

```
strip_dollars = function(x) { as.numeric(gsub("[\\$, ]", "", x)) }
lapply(data[ , c("x4", "x5", "x7", "x8")] , strip_dollars)
```

But in one particular currency column, I've few entries incuding parenthesis like **($2,345)**, $3,500, $5,600, **($3,234)**, .....
Hence, for this column the above code doesn't work. 
Please help me out with removing parenthesis & dollar sign from these entries.

Also, to identify columns containing currency data, I tried a lot including solutions given in [R - identify which columns contain currency data $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51364015/r-identify-which-columns-contain-currency-data?rq=1) but it doesn't work. Please suggest an optimal way of doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to step through what is replaced. I'm inferring that you do not want to lose the negative-ness suggested by the parens, so we'll do two steps:

```
s <- c("($2,345)", "$3,500", "$5,600", "($3,234)")
gsub("[$),]", "", s)
# [1] "(2345" "3500"  "5600"  "(3234"
```

This removes most of the junk (that we did not want/need to keep), now let's deal with the leading left-paren:

```
gsub("^\\s*[(]", "-", gsub("[$),]", "", s))
# [1] "-2345" "3500"  "5600"  "-3234"
```

From here, if needed, you can convert to `numeric`:

```
as.numeric(gsub("^\\s*[(]", "-", gsub("[$),]", "", s)))
# [1] -2345  3500  5600 -3234
```

This is not very robust to mal-formed strings. For instance, though I look for (and remove) leading space for the left-paren, anything else there will be a problem.

Comment: Great! It works. Please send the link of detailed explanation, I find gsub() confusing when it comes to special characters. Thanks

Comment: I just noticed more issue. lapply converts my dataframe into list and using as.data.frame gives error 'incorrect number of dimensions'. please suggest how to fix it.

Comment: Link of detailed explanation? Not sure what you mean ... my only reference for this is [`?gsub`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/grep.html). Note that some special characters lose their special-ness when contained within brackets (`[ ]`); for example, `(` and `)` are no longer group-definers when used within a character-class, ergo `[(]` will only match a paren; I find that notation simpler to use (and explain) then questioning whether I need backslashes.

Comment: For your `lapply` problem, try `data[ , c(x4, x5, x7, x8)] <- lapply(data[ , c(x4, x5, x7, x8)], strip_dollars)`. Note that `lapply` *by definition* will always return a `list`, there is no reason to expect anything different. The fact that `data.frame` is a special case of a `list` (all vectors are the same length), so by replacing a portion of a frame with the return of `lapply`, the whole object retains its frame-ness. If you are having other troubles with `lapply` that this does not resolve, either it's a new question or you need to provide reproducible data in your question.

Comment: To be clear: `lapply` is converting nothing. `data[,c(...)]` is technically a list, though it is also a frame. See `class(data[,c(...)])` and `is.list(data[,c(...)])` (using real column names in place of `...`) to see that it is both `"data.frame"` and `TRUE` (yes, a list). Perhaps once you realize the duality of frames, this behavior will make more sense.

Comment: One last "btw": using `data[ , c(x4, x5, x7, x8)]` is unintuitive (to me) with base frames: this means you have variables named `x4` (etc) that somehow contain the columns (either as integers or by name) to use. If you have columns named `"x4"` (etc), then it makes more sense to see `data[,c("x4","x5",...)]`. (If you are instead using `data.table`, then that might make sense but should be mentioned if it is important to you. Without that, I'm assuming "base" and therefore the `x4` vs `"x4"` differences.)

Comment: yeah, they are variable names, I just corrected. Thanks